# Global color settings for illustrator / keeps switching to gray

Tags: adobe-illustrator, rgb, color-profile, color-spaces

Is there a setting in illustrator that will make all of my colors, in all new projects, RGB? I'm not really sure why it often ends up as grayscale. I only use RGB for web assets and having to change if for small shapes all the time makes me sad.

Show me the magic setting please!

Comment: There's no way to make the Color Panel *stick* to a specific setting... it's been asked for.. and asked for.. and asked for.... and Adobe either can't or won't address it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a new document, choose the "Web" profile. The setting is sticky from session to session, and will remain at the last profile you chose. All swatch colors are RGB by default in web documents.

If you have a specific set of colors that you want to use in multiple documents, create a dummy document with those colors in the Swatches Panel. Choose `File > Save As Template`. Illustrator saves the template in its template directory, which is empty at the top level and contains only a subdirectory of called "Blank Template" that aren't relevant.

Any time you're creating a new document, click `Templates...` in the `File > New` dialog and load your template with your saved swatches. This is faster than saving out an ASE file, and lets you include gradients and patterns that the ASE format doesn't handle.

If you're doing web work for several different projects, make a named template for each project.